# WP_Error thrown after changing categories names to non latin characters

Tags: php, wordpress

I got this error:

> PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string

And this is my code:

```
<?php
  $taxonomyName = "gallery-category";
  $parent_terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));
  foreach ($parent_terms as $pterm) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $pterm->name, $taxonomyName ) . '"><img width="354" height="254" class="img-responsive center-block" src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/hotel-gallery.jpg"></a>';
    echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $pterm->name, $taxonomyName ) . '"><h3>' .$pterm->name. '</h3></a>';
  }
;?>
```

I think im getting the error by `$pterm->name` after i changed my categories name from english to japanese with non-latin characters. So how can I fix this error?

Comment: I think you have an extra `;` after foreach too

Comment: We are expected to know what get_terms does ? or get_term_link ? or what pterm is ? please add more information

Comment: I had a list of categories like this: Parent category > child category.......,Parent2 category > child ..... So $parent_terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false)); // this get top layer term of category which is Parent category then foreach to get name and permalink of that category.Everything work fine but if i translate category name to non-latin characters it'll give error with $pterm->name

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the error. My mistake to get permalink of a category, wordpress need:

```
get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy )
```

So `$term->name` will make it error.